# Allocate matrix of integer with c

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I have an integer 2d matrix NUMI and a 3d double matrix called `PROB`.

Here the 2 allocation:

```
   int main ( int argc, char* argv[]){
        double  ***PROB;
        int  **NUMI;    
        NUMI = (int **)malloc((dim)*sizeof(int *));
        PROB = (double ***)malloc((dim)*sizeof(double**));
        ...    
        for( i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            PROB[ACT][ACTSTART][i] = value;
            NUMI[i][i]= value2;
        }


}
```

- How many rows and cols has `NUMI`? Is a `dim x dim matrix`???
- `PROB` is a 3d matrix...here the allocation is `dim x dim x dim`?

Comment: Also all uppercase names are usually for macros. And one does not cast the return value of `malloc` etc. in C.

Comment: I know but it's not my code

Comment: Then it's unfortunate that the person who gave it to you did not properly tell you what it's doing.

Comment: What is `n`? What's in the `...` part? Your code is incomplete.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen pointers to pointers to pointers before. Why would anyone want such a thing?

Comment: yes it is, I'm going crazy

Comment: Don't use 2D or 3D matrixes in C. Use 1D array, and some accessor (e.g. `#define ELEM_2D(Mat,Width,I,J) (Mat)[(I)*(Width)+(J)]` ....)

Comment: Yes, unless you need 'ragged' rows (different lengths), allocating multi-dimensional arrays using piles of pointers is a recipe for extreme confusion and more potential for memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUMI does not have rows and columns, it is a pointer-to-pointer-to-int, and happens to be pointing at an allocated memory that has room for `dim` pointers-to-int, not `dim * dim` ints. This would be equivalent to treating as having been declared `int* NUMI[dim]`

A call

```
int* NUMI;
NUMI= malloc( dim*dim*sizeof(int) );
```

will allocate a `dim` by `dim` matrix of integers.

However, please note that with multi-dimensional arrays, say `int example[a][b]`, the size of the allocated area is equivalent to `int* example_ = malloc(a*b*sizeof(int))`, and the compiler works out the conversion from multidimensional indices to a single-dimension index, i.e. `example[c][d]` -> `example_[c*a+d]`

So when you do

```
int* NUMI;
NUMI= malloc( dim*dim*sizeof(int) );
//...
NUMI[i][i]= value2;
```

The compiler doesn't have the information required to convert from the multiple dimension to the single-dimension equivalent.

PROB is similar, pointing to a memory area with room for `dim` pointers-to-pointers-to-double, not `dim * dim * dim` doubles.
To get a `dim` cubed matrix, you'd need

```
double  *PROB;
PROB = (double *)malloc( dim*dim*dim*sizeof(double) );
```

and run into the same problem with multi-dimensional indices.

If dim is a compile-time constant, you can declare the multidimensional arrays directly without malloc

```
double PROB[dim][dim][dim];
int    NUMI[dim][dim];
```

The loop at the end of the main() should now work as expected.

If you must use malloc, either use malloc as described above:

```
NUMI= (int *)    malloc( dim*dim*sizeof(int) );
PROB = (double *)malloc( dim*dim*dim*sizeof(double) );
```

and modify the loop body to

```
PROB[(ACT * dim * dim) + (ACTSTART * dim ) + i] = value;
NUMI[i + dim * i]= value2;
```

Alternatively, call malloc in multiple loops as described by Alexey and Paolo.
With my solution, there is one `malloc()` call per variable, so each variable refer to a single contiguous memory area. With multiple `malloc()` calls in loops, you have multiple allocated memory areas that is unlikely to be contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You should allocate memory for every dimension:

```
NUMI = (int **)malloc((dim)*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    NUMI[i] = (int*)malloc(dim * sizeof(int));

PROB = (double ***)malloc((dim)*sizeof(double**));
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
{
    int j;
    PROB[i] = (double**)malloc(dim* sizeof(double*));
    for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
        PROB[i][j] = (double*)malloc(dim * sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NUMI` "is" an `l+1` array of pointers to `int`.
`PROB` "is" an `l+1` array of pointers of pointers to `double`.

This is closer to what you are looking for:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    size_t dim = 100;

    int **NUMI = (int **)malloc( dim * sizeof(int*) );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i )
        NUMI[i] = (int*)malloc( dim * sizeof(int) );

    double*** PROB = (double ***)malloc( dim * sizeof(double**) );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i )
    {
        PROB[i] = (double**)malloc( dim * sizeof(double*) );
        for( size_t j = 0; j < dim; ++j )
            PROB[i][j] = (double*)malloc( dim * sizeof(double) );
    }
    /// ...
    size_t ACT = 0, ACTSTART = 0;
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < dim; i++ )
    {
        PROB[ACT][ACTSTART][i] = 1;
        NUMI[i][i] = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
int **p;
int m=4,n=4,i;

/* Allocate memory */
p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int *) * m); /* Row pointers */
for(i = 0; i < m; i++) 
 {
      p[i] = (int) malloc(sizeof(int) * n); /* Rows */
 }
```

This will dynamically allocate an array with size [4][4]. Similarly it can be done to allocate for a 3-D array .