# Can we use this approach to allocate a 2d matrix- //let require dimensions be i*j int **p=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*i*j);

Tags: malloc

Can we use this approach to allocate a 2d matrix-

```
//let require dimensions be i*j     
int **p=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*i*j);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try, but it won't behave like you expect.

The allocation is for `i*j` `int`s, and that is fine. But when you access `p`, and I'm guessing you're expecting to do `p[x][y]` will not do what you expect.

`p[x]` has type `int*`, so the program will then look whatever memory address that is, and add `y * sizeof(int)` to that address and that's your value.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584315/allocate-matrix-of-integer-with-c/31586188#31586188) for more detail.